# Android keyboard slide animation

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have little (read: no) experience with animations in Android, but wanted to implement an animation for when the keyboard appears. Effectively, it would appear that the entire activity was sliding upwards (like the keyboard was below the activity and pushed it upwards), as opposed to only moving up so far as the selected `EditText`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: use android:uiMode="pan" in your manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An app receives no notification of when a keyboard appears, and the android framework itself is responsible for either sliding the app or laying it out again.  So customization isn't really possible.  Which is probably a good thing-  a keyboard is a separate app, and having written one I wouldn't want to even try to write the keyboard half of such an animation, we'd never get it to look right with all the various ways the app could do it.

The closest you'll get is to specify the fields to pan rather than resize when the keyboard is opened.

Comment: Just how do I do that?

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: Isn't that what the default is? I specified it and it changed nothing.

Comment: I honestly don't know what the default is.  But that's the only adjustment you can make to that.  The other option is adjustResize, which causes your app to be shrunk to fit the space above the keyboard.

Comment: Actually, I've been experimenting with a few of the different types of values, and none seem to change anything at all. Weird.

Comment: Interesting thought I just had-  the keyboard actually *could* do it if they wanted, because the keyboard has the ability to set its own size-  combined with pan if it increased its size slightly every 50ms it would be a sliding effect.  But that would break any field with Resize set badly (cause it to lay itself out repeatedly) so nobody would do it.

Answer (score 8):

In the latest version of Android OS (Android version 11), they added new set of APIs let you synchronize your app’s content with the IME (input method editor, aka soft keyboard) and system bars as they animate on and offscreen, making it much easier to create natural, intuitive and jank-free IME transitions.

### WindowInsetsAnimation.Callback

For frame-perfect transitions, a new insets [animation listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/WindowInsetsAnimation.Callback) notifies apps of per-frame changes to insets while the system bars or the IME animate.

[image]

### WindowInsetsAnimationController

Apps can take control of the IME and system bar transitions through the [WindowInsetsAnimationController](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/WindowInsetsAnimationController) API.

[image]